# No option in Toshiba BIOS for UEFI to CMS. system BIOS version 1.10 EC version 1.0

Tags: operating-systems

Am installing windows 8.1from a 3.0 USB stick.
I go into the BIOS, disable Secure Boot but there is no setting in the BIOS to disable UEFI. Nothing at all.
Now the machine will try to boot from the flash disk in the external drive. It tries and the access light on the drive flashes as it is being read and then it starts the boot from the hard drive. The flash is good as it works on other machines.

I have failed to install the OS on the computer.

Does anyone have any ideas? I know that the UEFI needs to be disabled but I don't see any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the issue. This was the SOLUTION:

-boot windows os directly on the hard drive using Rufus software(haven't tested using power ISO though) and a Hard Drive Enclosure,
-check 'list USB hard drives' on Rufus, change the partition scheme to 'MBR' (that is if your hard drive is in the MBR scheme).

- Specify the target system '**UEFI**.
- Then select file system as **fat32** - default
  and start boot installation.

After the process has finished put the hard drive back to the laptop and then boot the laptop from the USB stick.
Remember to: Have secure boot turned off.

Note: I choose this installation option because my computer is old-fashioned and has no "bios or UEFI, CSM" options in BIOS

It will send you to windows installation without errors.

I also had an issue before this I couldn't access bios at all so I removed the battery from the laptop and restarted it, this fixed the issue.

You can share your experience, Hope it helps.